# Graphs and surfaces

Tags: geometry, functions

Why is the graph, $G$, of a smooth function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ necessarily an "embedded surface"?

Thank you.

***Comment:*** I am starting to thing that there is a typo in the text. I think $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ so that the graph $G=(x,y,f(x,y))$. Assuming this is true, does the question make sense now?

Comment: There is no need to add «(EDITED)» to the title of questions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Sorry, deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want the graph *in $\mathbb{R}^3$* of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.  The easy way to see that this is an embedded surface is to define the map $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ via $F(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y))$ and check that $F$ is an embedding: it is

- injective,
- smooth, and
- $dF$ is everywhere full rank.

The first two are easy to check.  The third follows from the tact that 
$$dF = \begin{pmatrix}

1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\

\end{pmatrix}$$
always has trivial kernel.

(In fact, the graph of a smooth function is actually a two-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is slightly stronger than noting that it is an embedded surface.  Observe that we can produce new coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by "flattening" the graph down to the $xy$-plane.  The change-of-coordinate map is $\phi(x,y,z) = (x,y,z - f(x,y))$; it's a diffeomorphism, which means that the graph of $f$ has a coordinate chart in which it is the $xy$-plane, i.e., it is a two-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.)